# How to rename a package while building in Launchpad?

Tags: packaging, launchpad

Is it possible for a Launchpad packaging recipe to rename a package (from whatever there was in the control file) to something else?

Some developers name their packages `com.github.username.program` to ensure same naming conversions with snap and flatpak, but while installing from a Launchpad PPA, it will be much more convenient to `sudo apt install program` instead of `sudo apt install com.github.username.program`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upstream developer will keep the name `com.github.username.program` in both `debian/changelog` and `debian/control`. The control file has two fields to set the name, `Source` and `Package`. Keep the `Source` as is, and change the entry `Package` to `program`.

Now, push this change to a new branch in Launchpad, let's call it `name-fix`.

Now create a packaging recipe with the following contents.

```
# bzr-builder format 0.4 deb-version {debupstream}-0~{revno}
lp:bzr
merge name-fix lp:~name/of/the/name-fix/branch
```

If it is a git repo, use

```
# git-build-recipe format 0.4 deb-version {debupstream}-0~{revtime}
lp:bzr
merge name-fix lp:~contributor/+git/branch/name name-fix
```

As long as this line in the `debian/control` file is unchanged in upstream, there won't be any merge issues.
You can also modify other files in your new branch to apply more patches.  See the [detailed documentation for recipes](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/SourceBuilds/Recipes).

Comment: It would be really helpful if you add some more information about how to do this. Suppose I create another branch with modified `debian/control` file. But what about the rest of the files? Will I have to update them in that modified branch as well? Otherwise, won't there be merging issues?

Comment: @archisman-panigrahi I'm assuming that you're creating your branch starting from another branch that already contains the other files in `debian/` (since that's already a requirement to use recipes in the first place).  There'd only be merge conflicts if you change something that's later changed in a different way in the branch you started from.  That is, your branch wouldn't contain _just_ `debian/control`; it would be a branch of something else that contains (at least) all of `debian/`, with a commit on top that modifies `debian/control` and maybe other files as needed.

Comment: Yes, it works, I verified that I can apply patches this way. However, there is another problem. The upstream developer will add new lines to the `debian/changelog` with every new version, and this new line would contain `com.github.username.program`. So even if I create a new branch to change the name in `debian/control`, it would not work, as the changelog will have a the other name.

Comment: Ok, this can probably be fixed by changing the binary package name to `something` in `debian/control`, but keeping the source package name as it is.

Comment: Right, as you say.

Comment: You may be able to answer this. https://askubuntu.com/q/1343820/124466

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Sure - I've answered that question.